# how to get facebook friends list in facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get facebook friends list using facebook sdk 3.0 below code :

Try 1 :

```
    String result;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=" + token); 
    HttpResponse response;
    try
    {
         response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null)
            {
                result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.i("Request String",result);
                parseJSON(result);
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Try 2 :

```
new Request(
                    session,
                    "/me/friends",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                           Log.e("Responseee",""+response);

                           if (response.getError() == null) {

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        "getting data successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        response.getError()
                                                .getErrorMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        }
                    }
                ).executeAsync();
```

Try 3 :

```
new Request(
            session,
            "/me/friendlists",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                   // handle the result 
                    Log.i("Result: ", "Result: " + response.toString());
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Try 4:

```
String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid,name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN " +
                    "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
            session = Session.getActiveSession();

            Request request = new Request(session,
                    "/fql",                         
                    params,                         
                    HttpMethod.GET,                 
                    new Request.Callback(){       
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    Log.i("Result: ", "Result: " + response.toString());

                    try{
                        GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                        Log.d("data", jsonObject.toString(0));

                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){

                            JSONObject friend = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            Log.d("uid",friend.getString("uid"));
                            Log.d("name", friend.getString("name"));
                            Log.d("pic_square",friend.getString("pic_square"));             
                        }
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }                  
            }); 
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Above all tried getting below response.

Result: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}

I know facebook new SDK allow only those friends whose installed app..without this how to get friends details like birthdate,likes,etc., Please let me know what is the solution for new SDK.

Comment: How about RTFM... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: Hello Tobi,Yes I have added require permission.